# D3JS can't receive function?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, return

Ok, so I want to draw Arcs using D3 depending on the data. However, when I try to pass the value as a function it fails, if I pass it as a variable it works.

Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/paulocoelho/WyABt/1/

And heres the code:

```
var a = [[0.1, 0.4],[0.4,0.56],[0.56,1]];

var cfg = {
    w:200,
    h:200
};

var g = d3.select("#testdiv").append("svg").attr("width", cfg.w).attr("height", cfg.h).append("g")

var arct = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(cfg.h / 4)
        .outerRadius(cfg.h / 3)
        .startAngle(0)
        .endAngle(Math.PI);

// This one works
var path = g.selectAll("circleArcs").data(a).enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", arct)
    .style("fill","blue")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+cfg.w/2+","+cfg.h/2+")");

// This one does not!
var path2 = g.selectAll("circleArcs").data(a).enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", function(d,i){ return arct;})
    .style("fill","green");
```

So, right now the data is not hooked up but my point here is that I am passing exactly the same object `arct` but the one that goes though a function return is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `arct` is used in the first `path`, d3's `.attr` invokes the `arct` function.

[selection.attr(name[, value]](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-attr)

> ...if value is a function, then the **function is evaluated** [emphasis added] for each
>   selected element (in order)...

But in `path2`, when `arct` is returned inside the **outer** function, `.attr` runs the **outer** function , but the inner `arct` function does not automatically get invoked.

Here is a revised fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/pnQKY/2/

```
var path2 = g.selectAll("circleArcs").data(a).enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", function(){ 
        // console.log( typeof arct ); // "function": returns function reference, which does not get invoked inside of the outer function
        // console.log( typeof arct() ); // "string": returns value of invoked function 
        return arct();
     })
    .style("fill","green");
     ...
```

Hope this helps as a starting point.